# The connection was reset in IIS 7 for HTTP and HTTPS website after each server restart

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-services

I am currently hosting a website (running with MVC4 website) with HTTP and HTTPS in Windows Server 2008 R2 (IIS 7)

However, after each server restart, the site will always show "The connection was reset". I have to manually reconfigure the "IP Address" at "Binding" in IIS7.

Any possible way to trace how the issue could happened and anyway to fix it?

(Sidenote: I have similar website that hosted in IIS 8, Windows Server 2012 with same configuration, and the issue does not happened to the machine)

Update:
There is no trace in Event Viewer, so I have no idea what are the possible issues that happened.

Update:
The websites are virtual hosted on the same port in same server with binded DNS, where all of them using wildcard certificate based on domain for all HTTPS site. When I edit binding on one of the website with the HTTPS port, the rest of websites will work just fine without touching any binding.

Comment: Does your server have needed IP address at the time when IIS starts? Or may be it gets that IP a bit later?

Comment: @Jehy dont think so. The server itself is the one who hosted the site. So how can i auto assign the IP address (which may be the localhost of the server) when IIS start?

Comment: You might get a better response to this question on http://serverfault.com/